# max-width for cell in wide table

Tags: html, css, width, max, html-table

I have a table which is very wide.  Much wider than the width of the screen due to most of the columns having `white-space: nowrap`.

I have a few "wrapping" columns with `white-space: normal`.  These columns are squished extremely narrow.  Setting `width: 500px` has no effect.  Setting `min-width: 500px` forces the column to be 500px.

The problem is that I want the "wrapping" columns to take 0 to 500px depending upon the content of the column.  I want the "wrapping" columns to not take more than 500px but I want the column to take 500px to minimize the wrapping.  In other words, the "wrapping" column should expand up to 500px and then start wrapping.

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g8gy5m7z/) link shows the problem.  If the link isn't working, simply paste the following code into jsfiddle.net.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td style="max-width: 500px;">Hello World!  This is a very wide cell.  I hope it will wrap.  I am trying to make it very wide.  I might need some more text.</td>
                <td style="white-space: nowrap;">Hello World!  This is a very wide cell.  I hope it will wrap.  I am trying to make it very wide.  I might need some more text.</td>
                <td style="white-space: nowrap;">Hello World!  This is a very wide cell.  I hope it will wrap.  I am trying to make it very wide.  I might need some more text.</td>
                <td style="white-space: nowrap;">Hello World!  This is a very wide cell.  I hope it will wrap.  I am trying to make it very wide.  I might need some more text.</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Edit:**  A JavaScript solution would be okay.

Comment: You will need JavaScript/jQuery to realize this layout.  The CSS table layout algorithm will try to minimize the overall width of the table, and in this case, it achieves that by forcing the first column to wrap.  There is no CSS property or function that directs "expand content to certain length then start wrapping".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it using jQuery to determine when to start wrapping the text.  The only hard-coded parameter is the max width of 500px.

You need to wrap your content in the first column in a `div`.  The trick is to initially force the `div` to expand with non-wrapping text.  If the resulting width is greater than 500px, then set a width to the `div` and use normal white-space.

```js
var $div_w = $(".col1 div").width();

if ($div_w > 500) {
    $(".col1 div").addClass("wrapit");
}
```

```css
.col1 {
    width: auto;
}
.col1 div {
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 1px dashed blue;
}
.col1 div.wrapit {
    width: 500px;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td class="col1"><div>Hello World!  This is a very wide cell.  I hope it will wrap.  I am trying to make it very wide.  I might need some more text.</div></td>
        <td style="white-space: nowrap;">Hello World!  This is a very wide cell.  I hope it will wrap.  I am trying to make it very wide.  I might need some more text.</td>
        <td style="white-space: nowrap;">Hello World!  This is a very wide cell.  I hope it will wrap.  I am trying to make it very wide.  I might need some more text.</td>
        <td style="white-space: nowrap;">Hello World!  This is a very wide cell.  I hope it will wrap.  I am trying to make it very wide.  I might need some more text.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```